# Is it possible to use Grid Search with an externally defined scoring function?

Tags: scikit-learn, scoring, grid-search

I defined an external scoring function to determine cluster accuracy for handwritten digits, but cannot figure out how can I use that function in conjunction with GridSearchCV.

```
s = GridSearchCV(estimator = pipe_cl, 
                 param_grid = param_distributions,
                 scoring = my_scorer,
                 n_jobs=-1)


gs.fit(X_train, y_train)


y_pred_km = gs.predict(X_test)

my_scorer = make_scorer(clustering_accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred_km))
```

Comment: What is y_pred_km?

Comment: Supposed to be the cluster labels obtained from kmeans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`make_scorer` returns a new function, it takes a function as an argument. So this should work:

```
my_scorer = make_scorer(clustering_accuracy_score)
gs = GridSearchCV(estimator = pipe_cl, 
                 param_grid = param_distributions,
                 scoring = my_scorer,
                 n_jobs=-1)
gs.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!